# Pandas, how to pass list into a list position

Tags: python, pandas

```
def data_cleaning(df, dict):
    df = df[df.columns[list(dict.values())]
    return df
    
    
dict = {
  "cost": 0,
  "Price": 3
}
```

I am trying to pass the `dict` into `data_clearning()`
The thing is, once it accept list, it becomes `df.columns[[0, 3]]` with an extra bracket

How can I get the function runs as expected?

Best,

Comment: Is that keys or values ?

Comment: @BEN_YO, you are right, should be values

Comment: Looks like, you are trying to get cost and price columns from Dataframe. You could do '''df.loc(axis=1)[list(dict.keys())]''' .if this is not something, can you add input/output that you are expecting?

Comment: `df = df[list(dict.keys())].loc[list(dict.values())]` It looks like you wanna get columns of `keys` and rows of `value`. You should post what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `.iloc`

```
def data_cleaning(df, dict):
    df = df.iloc[:,list(dict.values())]
    return df
```

Comment: I think, you need to specify axis=1, if OP want to select columns.